# How can I get clang to save the command line to the object file

Tags: clang

I'm working with a fairly complicated build system, and I'd like to double check with arguments the compiler is getting by checking my object files, but it seems clang doesn't store this information.

Test file(test.c, should not be empty):

```
void func(){}
```

With gcc 4.8.4 and 9.4.0, `gcc -O3 -g -c test.c` produces test.o which includes the compiler command line. Output of `objdump -Ws test.o`

```
test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of the .debug_str section(paths omitted with x):

  0x00000000 66756e63 00746573 742e6300 2fxxxxxx func.test.c./xxx
  0x00000010 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  0x00000020 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  0x00000030 xxxxxxxx xxxx0047 4e552043 31372039 xxxxxx.GNU C17 9
  0x00000040 2e342e30 202d6d74 756e653d 67656e65 .4.0 -mtune=gene
  0x00000050 72696320 2d6d6172 63683d78 38362d36 ric -march=x86-6
  0x00000060 34202d67 202d4f33 202d6661 73796e63 4 -g -O3 -fasync
  0x00000070 68726f6e 6f75732d 756e7769 6e642d74 hronous-unwind-t
  0x00000080 61626c65 73202d66 73746163 6b2d7072 ables -fstack-pr
  0x00000090 6f746563 746f722d 7374726f 6e67202d otector-strong -
  0x000000a0 66737461 636b2d63 6c617368 2d70726f fstack-clash-pro
  0x000000b0 74656374 696f6e20 2d666366 2d70726f tection -fcf-pro
  0x000000c0 74656374 696f6e00                   tection.
```

However, with clang 3.8 and 10, `clang -O3 -g -c test.c` does not output compiler command line:

```
test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of the .debug_str section:

  0x00000000 636c616e 67207665 7273696f 6e20332e clang version 3.
  0x00000010 382e302d 32756275 6e747533 7e747275 8.0-2ubuntu3~tru
  0x00000020 73747935 20287461 67732f52 454c4541 sty5 (tags/RELEA
  0x00000030 53455f33 38302f66 696e616c 29007465 SE_380/final).te
  0x00000040 73742e63 002fxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx st.c./xxxxxxxxxx
  0x00000050 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  0x00000060 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
  0x00000070 66756e63 00                         func.
```

Is there a flag to request clang store the flags given to the compiler driver into the debug_str section as gcc does?